# What kind of notation is $\pi: b\ \varnothing\ M$?

Tags: notation, fiber-bundles

In the paper [Magnetic Bloch analysis and Bochner Laplacians](https://www.academia.edu/65733916/Magnetic_Bloch_analysis_and_Bochner_Laplacians) of Ruedi Seiler, this expression appears in this context:

[image]

The conventional notation for a fiber bundle would be $\pi: b\ \to\  M$.
where $\pi$ is a continuous surjection from $b$ to $M$. Does $\varnothing$ mean a continuous surjection? Is this a conventional notation for this? Or does it mean something else here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like bad OCR to me. Below screenshot of the paper from different source.

[image: screenshot of the paper]